# Use Pusher or similar libraries to auto update view from database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pusher

I am developing an application in Rails in which I am providing users the option to edit the content of a database through an HTML table. But i want to make this collaborative so that when a user updates anything, the view of other users gets updated automatically.

I am calling AJAX functions to save/update the data.

With this I can use polling in which client will continuously ask the server if there are any updates. But this will be inefficient.

Searching the web I found that I can use web sockets and for that I can use libraries such as Pusher, Slanger.

But i am not finding anything on how can I use these libaries to auto update the HTML table.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not interested in polling, then a pub/sub server is probably what you're looking for.

I would suggest checking out [Juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut). It allows client browsers to establish long-running connections to your server that don't poll: instead, when your server sends a push, they respond by rendering the JavaScript from that push directly onto the client page.

The author of Juggernaut has a sample project called [Holla](https://github.com/maccman/holla) that does almost exactly what you're looking for -- that is, it subscribes to a server, and upon reading from the connection it updates the page the client is on. Holla uses it to create a chat service but you can use the same code to update the table for other users viewing it.

Comment: thnx Veraticus. what is the advantage of push sockets over polling? i think push socket also use polling internally. i may be wrong. can u please clarify this? and i looked at Juggernaut, looks really useful thanks again..

Comment: Juggernaut does not use polling internally; it uses a persistent websocket connection to the server. Websockets are much more efficient than polling for server resources. Polling requires a server connection to be opened and a database query be made and a view be rendered ever X seconds, even if nothing has changed since then... whereas polling notifies the client when a change has been made, resulting in a more efficient communication method.

Comment: i think in the last line of your last comment(whereas polling...) you want to say 'Push sockets'.  yes i got your point. also how can library know what rows/fields have been modified. or it just updates all the data. say in my case i need to refresh only those cells that have been updated.(like google spreadsheet refreshes only required cells) so do i need to maintain flags for that? or library has some support for that.

Comment: i configured my system to use juggernaut. 
by following https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut_plugin

but juggernaut server is not starting
it keeps saying Starting Juggernaut server 0.5.8 on port: 5001... on terminal but never starts.

help me figure out what i am missing.

Comment: juggernaut_plugin is not what you want. Follow the link I posted earlier to [the github page](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut), the much more recent and more updated version of Juggernaut.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use any of this, but a quick google for pusher.js seems, that this is easy enough. On the Browser side you define an event handler.

On the server side you can trigger events and together with the event send some data (eg a created record). This can either be a string or a hash. A hash will be converted to JSON.

Whatever kind of data you send you can then use any library like jquery or similar to create new row in a table (or generate whatever html you need). 
In the Rails context using render to generate a html-string instead of JSON would allow you to use partials and templates. Again it's easy to insert them into the DOM with jquery.

There is even a gem for Ruby on Rails that integrates pusher functionality. See the [pusher tutorial](http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries)

I guess, other libraries like slanger will work more or less the same way.

Comment: thnx, but pusher is not free. it provides some limited connections to free users. and u told that you dont use any of them, then how to send information to clients from server. say when a row is updated. how can clients/users be notified that some data is updated (without using library like pusher)

Comment: @mashit: Your question was how to use these libraries to update html. There are quite a lot of technologies that allow something like this, but it may become quite difficult to set this up, especially if you are limited to free software. I think [this article](http://jordanhollinger.com/2011/05/15/writing-an-ajax-long-polling-server-in-ruby-part-1) shows some way to do it.

Comment: thnx thorsten. your answer was useful.